# How can I use ng-click in a custom polymer element?

Tags: angularjs, polymer

Can I use AngularJS' ng-click directive on elements found within a custom Polymer element? For instance, in my Angular controller, I define a function on the scope and when I'm in the index.html, using that function is a simple as `ng-click="function_name();"`:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.function_name = function() { alert('test'); };
  });
```

And my HTML:

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <a ng-click="function_name();">Click Me</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I want to use that same function from within a polymer element, `ng-click="function_name();"` seems to do nothing:

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="simple-test">
  <div>
    <a ng-click="function_name();">Click Me</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    Polymer('simple-test', {});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcem7/

Comment: your controller stops after your first `</div>` You need to wrap both in the same div or add another `ng-controller`. That is why the second line isn't doing anything

Comment: @Ronnie: You are right, although I guess I made this without the disclaimer that ideally I'd have everything live within their own imports rather than all in one file. Even if I move the imports into the controller tag the imported HTML files won't be able to use `ng-click`

Answer (score 2):

Polymer has it's own flavor for event delegation:

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="simple-test">
<template>
  <div>
    <a on-click="{{aClick}}">Click Me</a>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('simple-test', {
    aClick: function(event) {
    }
  });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

You can do `on-<any event name>` to delegate arbitrary events.

Comment: But now this lives within Polymer's scope and I can't leverage what I have in Angular. What if its a function that I want to share between the two? would `on-click` in Polymer be able to access the `function_name` code in my Angular controller?

Comment: Functions can live anywhere, what's not clear is if the function needs scope-specific access. You shouldn't mix Polymer and Angular scopes. If you want to use `ng-click` put it on the Polymer element itself and not inside the shadow-root. E.g. `<simple-test ng-click="...">`.